# How to change type of values in list from strings to integers

Tags: python, list, integer

I want to convert values in `list_a` into integers.

```
list_a = ['20.3', '35', '10', '6.74', '323']

for i in list_a:
    print int(i) * 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use map.
With Python2:

```
>>> list_a = ['20.3', '35', '10', '6.74', '323']
>>> list_a = map(float, list_a)
>>> list_a[0]*2
40.6
```

In Python3, map returns an iterator instead of list. So, with Python3:

```
>>> list_a = list( map(float, list_a) )
```

Comment: doesn't work as-is in python 3

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for pointing. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually need to convert your strings to floats because they have decimal points, and not integers.

Simple way: Create an empty list, and loop through your original list. Append items from the new list into the empty list while doing modifications. You have the modification down, which is good:

```
list_a = ['20.3', '35', '10', '6.74', '323']
list_b = []
for i in list_a:
    list_b.append(float(i)*10)
```

If you want a more complex solution, you can use a list comprehension:

```
list_b = [float(i)*10 for i in list_a]
```

These are equivalent solutions.

Finally, you can actually modify the elements of list_a by using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, j in enumerate(list_a):
    list_a[i] = float(j)*10
```

Comment: But `int()` on 20.3 will raise error

Comment: @kuro Oops, fixed

Comment: But they want `int`s not `float`s (although I admit the question is a bit unclear)

Comment: @Chris_Rands It's rather hard to know what OP wants without seeing an expected output, so I'll leave my answer as such for now and await any edits/responses

Comment: @TerryA, you missed the `enumerate()` in the actual code

Comment: @kuro Lol -- It's been a long day

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = ['20.3', '35', '10', '6.74', '323']


for i in range(len(list_a)):
    list_a[i] = int(list_a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [round(float(i) * 10) for i in a]
```

Returns list of ints in Python 2.

Comment: Not in Python2, it returns a float.